# Jenkins internal working

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, build-automation

What actually happens in Jenkins when you select build automatically whenever there is a push to remote repository? How Jenkins comes to know about whether a push was made to the repository or not?

Comment: it polls the repo at specified interval to do that.

Comment: Can you just tell what is the poll interval? As it triggers the build action immediately. @Asdfg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the git plugin it gets triggered via web hook. Here is a link that explains it better than i could: https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github/

Comment: Thanks @Frankenstein. Got your point the webhook configured on github settings is the one responsible for automatic build triggering whenever there is a push made.